# Sync Method call Async Method with Async Methods inside

Tags: asynchronous

For each Method i want create Sync and Async, But without duplicating the code. I f I call an Async Method with other Async Methods inside, is it a correct code?.

```
public void MethodA(){//1
    MethodAAsync().GetAwaiter();        
}

public void MethodA(){//2 is it a correct code
    MethodB();
    MethodC();
    ...code
    ...code
    ...code
    MethodD();
    MethodE();  
}

public async Task MethodAAsync(){
    await MethodBAsync(cancellationToken);
    await MethodCAsync(cancellationToken);
    ...code
    ...code
    ...code
    await MethodDAsync(cancellationToken);
    await MethodEAsync(cancellationToken);
}

//1 or 2
```

Answer (score 4):

[Synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods is an antipattern](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/). First, I recommend that you only support an asynchronous API. But sometimes this isn't possible, e.g., for backwards compatibility reasons.

In that case, I recommend the [boolean argument hack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development), which looks something like this:

```
public void MethodA() {
  MethodACore(sync: true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

public Task MethodAAsync() {
  return MethodACore(sync: false);
}

private async Task MethodACore(bool sync) {
  if (sync) MethodB(); else await MethodBAsync(cancellationToken);
  if (sync) MethodC(); else await MethodCAsync(cancellationToken);
  ...code
  ...code
  ...code
  if (sync) MethodD(); else await MethodDAsync(cancellationToken);
  if (sync) MethodE(); else await MethodEAsync(cancellationToken);
}
```

Comment: Why do we use `.GetAwaiter.GetResult()` instead of `.Result`?

Comment: `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` avoids an `AggregateException` wrapper in the case where `MethodACore` throws an exception.

Comment: I was told that calling Async method and awaiting on it to get Sync version is an antipattern and can cause deadlocks.

Comment: @SaherAhwal: That is correct. However, this pattern is not blocking on asynchronous code, since the core method is guaranteed to complete synchronously.