# What is the best practice to call Async method from Sync method?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, synchronization

I know some people will argue "why don't you just make SyncMethod() to async method?". We wish, but in a real world, sometimes we have to keep SyncMethod the way it is for backwards compatibility reasons.

Here is the situation. We have a deadlock with the following code.

```
public void SyncMethod()
{
    var serviceResult = ProcessDataAsync().Result;
}

public await ServiceResult ProcessDataAsync()
{
    //Do other things
    await GetDataFromApiAsync();
}

private static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient(); 
public await ApiResult GetDataFromApiAsync()
{
    var response = await Client.GetAsync("http://api.com/getJson");
    dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    return obj;  
}
```

**Option 1**: Use Task.Run and get task.Result. This solves the deadlock issue but it's forced to run in a new thread, outside of the synchronization context of the originating thread. However, there's certain environments where this is very ill-advised: particularly web applications. Is it a good practice?

```
public void SyncMethod()
{
    Task<decimal> task = Task.Run<decimal>(async () => await ProcessDataAsync());
    var serviceResult = task.Result;
}
```

**Optoin 2**: add ConfigureAwait(false) all the way down from Sync to the last async method.

```
public void SyncMethod()
{
    var serviceResult = GetDataFromApiAsync().ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();;
}

public await ServiceResult ProcessDataAsync()
{
    //Do other things
    await GetDataFromApiAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

private static HttpClient Client = new HttpClient(); 
public await ApiResult GetDataFromApiAsync()
{
    var response = await Client.GetAsync("http://api.com/getJson").ConfigureAwait(false);
    dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
    return obj;  
}
```

**Option 3**: [Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63695309/559648).

```
public void SyncMethod()
{
    var serviceResult = GetDataFromApiAsync().(sync: true).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

All these solutions will solve the deadlock issue. My question is what the best practice would be?

Comment: Best practice is to not wrap async calls into sync calls (as it's stated in answer where 3rd option came)

Comment: ^^ And he says: Don't. (Except you absolutely have to.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call asynchronous method from synchronous method in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann, of course, I've seen that question before I made this post. No, it doesn't answer my question but it add more options to my question.

Comment: well, then my view is: if you have any technical constraints that make the answer obvious, then use that option. if not, then: all options have pros and cons, and this question is _opinion-based_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> what the best practice would be?

There **is no best practice**, and here's why:

Every hack works in some situations and does not work in other situations. There is no hack that works in all situations. If there was a hack that worked everywhere, then that would be what everyone would use and that hack would be the best practice. But there isn't a hack that works everywhere, so there is no "best practice". There **is no** general-purpose solution.

The [various hacks are described in this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development), along with a description of the situations where each one works and doesn't.

Comment: no best practice with NET 5, NET 6 , ...?

Comment: @Kiquenet No. There is no solution that can work in all situations.

Comment: Are there solutions for any situations? Not for all situations, for some situations.

Comment: @Kiquenet: Yes; see the article linked in my answer.